# mingw produces broken .exe

Tags: c++, mingw

I have installed the newest MinGW suite. My project still compiles without any error but the produced executable is not working. Starting it results in the well known windows xp error message. Paradoxically source code like

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main()
{
    printf("test\n");
    return 0;
}
```

produces a working executable while

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << "test\n" << std::endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

compiles fine but the executable is broken as described above.

Before i made the update everything worked. So what goes wrong here?

Comment: Are you using g++ to build it or gcc -libstdc++ ?

Comment: wow your answer was fast! i use g++.

Comment: What is "the well known windows xp error message" ...?

Comment: I don't suppose we can convince you to use the (free) compilers in the Windows SDK instead?

Comment: The well known windows xp error goes like:

Comment: ... has encountered a problem and needs to close. We are sorry for the inconvenience. Send error report, dont send....

Comment: i am using eclipse cdt so mingw and its integrated toolchains seem to be an easy solution.

Comment: @golmman : If you're using the official MinGW distribution, I would strongly recommend you use [TDM-GCC](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/) instead.

Comment: What's the exception code in "Stopped Working..." dialog box? You can also view the exception code in Windows Event Viewer.

Comment: Just recently I found mingw generating wrong x87 instructions which sucks especially when pulling an allnighter for an assignment. VC++ all the way for me now :>

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the libstdc++-*.dll in the path? It may be shared in newer MinGW versions, and std::cout uses it.

Answer (score 0):

A tool like [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) will probably tell you what is actually going wrong in more detail, and possibly even tell you what you need to fix to make it work.